# Need code to understand synchronized static and non-static methods being accessed at the same time by two different threads on the same instance

Tags: java, multithreading, static, synchronized, java-threads

```
class A
{
    synchronized static void m1()
    {
        System.out.println("In m1 A");
    }
    synchronized void m2()
    {
        System.out.println("In m2 A");
    }
}
```

There are two threads T1 and T2. T1 is accessing m1 method. Will T2 be able to access m2 method on the same instance at the same time?

The above para & code are a question asked on a learning resource . And the answer was "Yes, two threads can access two methods, one static sync and another non-static sync at the same time on the same instace".

I want to understand this with the help of a small code snippet , but unable to write one. Could you'll please help me.

P.S : I found the answer to what I was looking for. One question was how can a static method be called using the instance. I've covered that as well in my answer. Thanks for people who have pitched in their comments without making condescending statements.

Comment: Why would you need to from us? You already have "A" and creating two threads is no rocket science (you also say you already have them), so you have can test that situation yourself.

Comment: @Tom - I do not have the code. I was studying this somewhere and Im wondering how can we achieve this.

Comment: @Tom - i am aware of creating two threads, yes. But i'm not sure how do you call one methods from one thread and another method from another.

Comment: "on the same instance" static methods aren't accessed on an instance.

Comment: They can execute at the same time: the monitor is different, `A.class` for static and `this` for non static. You can check by putting a breakpoint in each and invoking both simultaneously and seeing if they both get hit (with pause set to thread on breakpoint hits).

Comment: @AndyTurner , Yes that's what i was wondering . But how can two threads even access two methods at the same time

Comment: @BeUndead Could you please provide the driver code which can execute what im trying to understand

Comment: Not without modifying this code to accept a lock of some sort (CountDownLatch or similar) since it’s just a race in the JVM. That’s why I suggested breakpoints.

Comment: [Here's](https://ideone.com/ortLAh) a demo showing both methods being entered, without resorting to calling it thousands of times and hoping for a collision.

Comment: @BeUndead thank you so much. I will try to understand this and get back

Answer (score 0):

> I found what I was looking for , correct me if i am wrong

```
public class ObjecAndClassLevelLock
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ThreadExample te=new ThreadExample();

        Thread t1= new Thread(() -> te.m1());
        Thread t2=new Thread(()->ThreadExample.m2());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}


class ThreadExample extends Thread
{
    public synchronized void m1(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("Sync Method");
    }
    public static synchronized void m2(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("Static Sync Method");
    }
}
```

Comment: I added example that make a lot of calls to those methods since your code call only once so most chances that it will not happen simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

```
 final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.submit(()->{
            A a = new A();
            for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                a.m2();
        });

        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            A.m1();
```